# How to detect a broadcast receiver when app is closed?

Tags: java, android

I have a broadcast receiver and I want to run some code when a certain event happens even if the app is not running.

My code is shown below

MainActivity.java

```
package kenneth.menuactivator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textchange;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textchange = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP ) {
                broadcastIntent();
               textchange.setText("Menu Pressed");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP ) {
            event.startTracking();
               return true;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;    
    }

    public void broadcastIntent()
       {
          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction("kenneth.menuactivator.CUSTOM_INTENT");
          sendBroadcast(intent);
       }
}
```

Receiver.java

```
package kenneth.menuactivator;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          //some code

       }

    }
```

I have added the permission in manifest. The code works fine when the app is running. But the app is closed it is not working. Or is there any other way I can detect events even when the app is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are listening over KeyEvents on your activity, when the activity is running it works fine, wich is expected, but when the app is not running, so is not your activity so you can't get triggers on your keyevents,

Comment: Is there any other way to start an event/app using buttons at lock screen